# how do i make multiple subscriptions to socket io client and selectively unsubscribe some of them?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, client

How do I selectively unsubscribe socket.on() calls in the client? The official document is unclear and I dont see why socket? e.g. I've got multiple socket.on("uuid") calls in my client and I want to unsubscribe some while keeping others open. is this even possible?

The documentation references socket.removeListener(eventName, listener) but there's no documentation on it!

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: if you want to keep the eventName same for both case, then send an additional flag into the data and close the connection for the unsubscribe client and continue for subscribed clients

Comment: Thanks Rajesh are you aware of any code examples. its specifically client side js im trying to work with...

Comment: [disconnect](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-disconnect-close) can use this with conditions a/c to your use case

Comment: i don't want to disconnect on the server. i need to unsubscribe a single  socket.on() in the client whilst leaving other socket.on() connections open. this appears to be a major limitation of socket.io...